# Randomly tomcat process create another copy process of it. Now see two PIDs of tomcat running

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7, sysdeo

i observed strange problem suddenly on one of our QA machine.
We keep tomcat started using sysdeo eclipse plugin on windows server.

Application was in use for few days, working fine. No changes done on server.
Suddenly we observed today http://localhost:8080 stuck and not giving response.
Taskmanager found 2 tomcat process running with same no of threads around 1500.

PID 12309 with command line property :
 "..\javaw.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:52742 "-Dcatalina.home=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50" "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\endorsed" "-Dcatalina.base=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\temp" -Xmx25000m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\bootstrap.jar;..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

PID 56098 with command line property : 
"..\javaw.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:61684 "-Dcatalina.home=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50" "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\endorsed" "-Dcatalina.base=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\temp" -Xmx25000m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\bootstrap.jar;..\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Please give pointers on solving this problem.

Comment: What's the parent process of each of those? Do you have any scheduled jobs that launch Tomcat?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no we manually start tomcat from eclipse using sysdeo plugin start stop button but there is tomcat cluster setup under mod_jk balancer of 2 nodes with session replication... we observed this on one node only.

Comment: Wait... you deploy from within Eclipse in a pre-prod environment? :/

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz yes we build deploy from eclipse and then start tomcat server from eclipse only using sysdeo plugin as that gives us freedom to put breakpoints to analyze issues which saves lot of time.

Comment: Well, if you use Eclipse to manage your deployments, is it possible that you have inadvertently deployed the application twice? All it takes is one stray click...

Comment: as i mentioned deployment was done already, nobody touched the enviorment...it was in use working properly for few days and suddenly this happened, i am sure not related to deployment.